# AJAX POST request error - `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Tags: django, ajax

If I try to do this, I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

```
$(document).on('input', '#search-inp', (e) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/search/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                input: $('#search-inp').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]'),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

And if I try to do this, I get this error:
`403: Forbidden`

```
$(document).on('input', '#search-inp', (e) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/search/',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: {
                input: $('#search-inp').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]'),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

```
# This is my views.py
def search(request):
    return JsonResponse(data={
        'test': 'test'
    })
```

What could be the problem?
Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: try to add url like this in your ajax code `url : '{% url 'search' %}',`

Answer (score 1):

I am so sorry that I bothered everyone.

```
$(document).on('input', '#search-inp', (e) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/search/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                input: $('#search-inp').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

I had done this: `csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]')`

But should do this: `csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()`